# macbook pro Mac OS X 10.13.4 Office365 Bounce Spam Email

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, email, office-365

I get so much spam emails (you know the ones offering SEO, first page results for google etc etc.)

I've set up a few blocks in rules for Office 365 email but not sure I've done it correctly.

How can I tell that the rules are working or catch more bad emails?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If no one answers, consider honing the details with another edit (use the edit button above and to the left of my edit and icon) to show what sort of rule you set up or what menu item you used to block the spam. Perhaps we can show you a better way, but hard to guess what you did with your rules.